# RestKit post with NSArray of NSDictionary numbering

Tags: post, nsarray, nsdictionary, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am using RestKit to Post an object to the server.
The object contains an NSArray, which I convert to NSDictionaries before adding it to the parameters list (an NSDictionary)

the NSDictionary queryParams looks like this (printed out using NSLog, and removing some fields for clarity)

requestParams = {

```
"app_version" = "v1.0(1.006)";
"extended_information" =     {
    "travel_locations" =         (
                    {
            "Aircard_or_Tablet" = 0;
            Country = "United States";
            "End_Date" = "04/12/2013";
            "Start_Date" = "03/12/2013";
        }
    );
    "using_voice" = 0;
};
```

}

I then send it:

```
[objectManager postObject:nil path:server_path parameters:requestParams success:… failure:…]
```

The problem is that when RestKit creates the query string, it seems to increment the counter for each key in the dictionary, rather than per item in the array. The following is what is received by the server. I added a line break after each parameter for clarity:

```
app_version=v1.0(1.006)
&extended_information[travel_locations][0][Aircard_or_Tablet]=0
&extended_information[travel_locations][1][Country]=United States
&extended_information[travel_locations][2][End_Date]=04/12/2013
&extended_information[travel_locations][3][Start_Date]=03/12/2013
&extended_information[using_data]=0
```

The server is expecting (and I would expect) travel_locations to remain at [0] for all the keys in that one object, like this:

```
app_version=v1.0(1.006)
&extended_information[travel_locations][0][Aircard_or_Tablet]=0
&extended_information[travel_locations][0][Country]=United States
&extended_information[travel_locations][0][End_Date]=04/12/2013
&extended_information[travel_locations][0][Start_Date]=03/12/2013
&extended_information[using_data]=0
```

And, of course, if a second travel_location were there it would have [1], the third would have [2], and so forth.

Is this a bug in RestKit? Is there a better way I can be sending this request so that it does work? I do not have the option of changing the server.

To question is:
**How can I have RestKit convert the NSDictionary for parameters properly so that it does not increment the array index identifier for each key in the array object?**

Thanks,
-Nico

Comment: Why are you using RestKit for this?

Comment: RestKit makes all the rest of the communications very easy. Just this one detail seems to be a problem. But good point, I could just implement this specific call the way I had it in the previous version (without RestKit).

Comment: RestKit is built on top of AFNetworking...